isolating wireguard networks on the same server
I use a small linux VPC to host my own wireguard VPN and recently added another VPN for my friends to use. So at the moment I have 2 wireguard interfaces on the server wg0 (10.0.0.0/28) and wg1 (10.0.0.16/28) and I'd like to block any traffic between them. So clients from wg0 can't reach anything in wg1 and vice versa, while allowing clients from each of the VPNs to reach the internet.

What have you tried so far?

This sounds like you need a couple of deny rules on the forward chain - what issue(s) are you encountering?

@Cpt.Whale - I searched the internet a lot and it seems like I should be able to achieve this by creating some FW rule (like DavidT suggests as well), but I have little experience with writing more involved iptables (or nftables) rules apart from opening a port ..

I gave up on trying to do this with firewalld and gave ufw a go and it turned out to be as easy as:
ufw insert 1 deny from 10.0.0.0/28 to 10.0.0.16/28
ufw insert 1 deny from 10.0.0.16/28 to 10.0.0.0/28

The insert 1 is important to make sure this deny rule is inserted at the top of the rules and evaluated with the highest priority otherwise you're risking that some allow rule gets matched earlier.
Update for firewalld (couldn't lose this battle..):

put each wg interface in its zone (e.g. wg0, wg1)
use rich rules to block any 10.x.x.x traffic traffic coming from other wireguard interfaces:

so for wg0:
firewall-cmd --zone=wg0 --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" destination address="10.0.0.0/0.0.0.15 priority=0" accept'
firewall-cmd --zone=wg0 --add-rich-rule='rule priority="1" family="ipv4" destination address="10.0.0.0/0.255.255.255" drop'

for wg1:
firewall-cmd --zone=wg1 --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" destination address="10.0.0.16/0.0.0.15 priority=0" accept'
firewall-cmd --zone=wg1 --add-rich-rule='rule priority="1" family="ipv4" destination address="10.0.0.0/0.255.255.255" drop'

note: The filters in rich rules use wildcards for the network range instead of subnets.
